# How to capture all user events that produced javascript errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, user-controls, dom-events, user-input

I am building error monitor to send and capture all JavaScript errors. I want to capture all user events so that it will be helpful to reproduce those errors. How can I capture events something similar to what paid services like trackJS does?

Please also give details about cross browser compatibility issues?

Comment: You would save yourself a lot of time and heartbreak to just use [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com) instead :)